# How to apply a Select Case statement?

Tags: vba

Why does the Select Case statement show the message "No"?

It should be "Bubble".

```vb
Sub Macro1()
Dim Resolução As Integer
Resolução = 7

Select Case Resolução
    Case Resolução = 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
        MsgBox ("Ghost")

    Case Resolução = 1
        MsgBox ("Car")

    Case Resolução = 7, 8
        MsgBox ("Bubble")
   
    Case Else
        MsgBox ("No")

End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong syntax for the cases.

Rather than

```
Case Resolução = 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

use

```
Case 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

And similarly for the other cases.

With what you are doing, you are using a Boolean value (the result of a comparison such as `Resolução = 0`) as a case label.